# How to export MongoDB long format collection as wide format csv

Tags: mongodb, export

I have mongodb collection in the following format

```
brand1,trouser
brand1,jeans
brand2,belt
brand2,shoes
brand2,jeans
```

I want to export this data as csv file in the following format

```
brand1,trouser,jeans,belt
brand2,belt,shoes,jeans
```

can someone please help me.

Comment: would $group do what you need?

Comment: @Joe I am not sure.. can you please show me how to do it with $group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the answer for the question.

`db.brand.aggregate([{ $group : { _id: "$brand_id", "items": { $push: '$item'  } }}], {allowDiskUse : true})`

It gives the result as follows:

`{ "_id" : "brand1","items" : [ 'trouser','jeans'] }`

`{ "_id" : "brand2","items" : [ 'belt','shoes','jeans'] }`